# How to change direction of object in move transition in animation in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, transition

I want to change direction of an image in android animation.My fragment is

```
public class IconAnimation  extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.icon_animation, container,false);  
    return v;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId())
    {   
        case R.id.comedy:
            Animation animation1 AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), 
            R.anim.slide);
            ImageView image= (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.startAnimation(animation1);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

and My animation XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">
<translate
  android:fromXDelta="0%p"
  android:toXDelta="150%p"
  android:duration="800"
  />
```

Its output is something like this:[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe0vO.png)
But I want something like this:[expected outout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YluXt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    final TranslateAnimation animationt1 = new TranslateAnimation(fromXoffset, toXOffset, fromYoffset,toYoffset);
    animationt1.setDuration(300);
    animationt1.setFillAfter(true);
    animationt1.setAnimationListener(this);
    yourView.startAnimation(animation1);
```

Comment: Thanks but what value should I pass to fromXoffset, toXoffset, fromYoffset ,toYoffset?

Comment: from should 0,i.e the starting point of your view. toXoffset is horizontal direction.. -x is right to left and +x is left to right. similarly fromYoffset is 0, starting view of y. and toyoffset is vertical direction. top to bottom is -y and bottom to tpo is +y

Comment: This code worked for me
     <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="100"
        android:toXDelta="76%p" />
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="800"
        android:toYDelta="-10%p" />
    
        <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="1300"
        android:toXDelta="75%p" />

Comment: can you see a tick mark down to downvote for my answer?

Comment: if any of the answer is quite helpful you can even upvote that answer so that it reaches maximum people and they can get max benefit out of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also by XML :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >
 <!-- Use startOffset to give delay between animations -->
<!-- Move -->
<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="700"
    android:toXDelta="50%p" />
<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="800"
    android:toYDelta="-10%p" />
 <translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="1300"
    android:toXDelta="75%p" />
```